# Tracking changes to the DOM element

Tags: javascript

After the page is loaded, the class "active" may switch from d-1 to d-2. 
I need to make the class "duble" switched from l-1 to l-2 automatically at this time.

```
<li id="l-1" class="duble"></li>
<li id="l-2"></li>

<div id="d-1" class="active"></div>
<div id="d-2"></div>
```

Comment: You need to post what you tried.

Comment: Save the active class to localstorage, then write a function that grabs the localstorage value on pageload, checks it against the DOM class and, if it is different, update the other class.

Comment: How would it *switch*? Through your code?